# Access 2010 - SubReports Spacing

Tags: ms-access, report, subreport

I am having an issue where when I am in design view on the report I have two subreports on top of each other and it looks like it should preview just fine for the report but then when i take a look at it in report view or print preview it shows the report on the bottom of the top report on a new page even though there is nearely to no spacing between the subreports in design view. I've tried shrinking the subreport, making the text smaller and nothing is working.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the main report in design view and in print preview? Upload to imgur.com and add the links to your question.

Comment: Here are the screen shots for the issue im having with access: http://i.imgur.com/NOJ1IFD.jpg designview image; http://i.imgur.com/EFo6zxh.jpg printpreview page 1; http://i.imgur.com/tnvbxfA.jpg printpreview page 2.

Comment: Thanks. But: the second screenshot, which might be the most interesting one, is "no longer available". --- Are the subreports left and right set to "Can grow = Yes"?

Comment: Yeah i set the settings to Yes for 'Can Shrink' and 'Can Grow'. Im gonna reupload my image for you again, here: http://i.imgur.com/fgdL3ys.jpg should work now, i tested the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the subreports on the left and right are the problem.

If they are set to "Can grow = Yes", they will force the bottom subreport to be printed below their bottom border.

To prevent this, you will have to combine the two subreports in the middle into one subreport (you can nest subreports).

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I have combined the two subreports into one and my report is looking much better now. Thank you again!